# Using NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I have the following requirements for a server/client architecture:

1. Write a server/client that works asynchronously.
2. The communication needs to be a duplex, i.e., reads and writes on both ends.
3. Multiple clients can connect to the server at any given time.
4. Server/client should wait until they become available and finally make a connection.
5. Once a client connects it should write to the stream.
6. Then the server should read from the stream and write response back to the client.
7. Finally, the client should read the response and the communication should end.

So with the following requirements in mind I've written the following code but I'm not too sure about it because the docs for pipes are somewhat lacking, unfortunately and the code doesn't seems to work correctly, it hangs at a certain point.

```
namespace PipesAsyncAwait471
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO.Pipes;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task> {
                HandleRequestAsync(),
            };

            tasks.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => SendRequestAsync(i, 0, 5)));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        private static async Task HandleRequestAsync()
        {
            using (NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe",
                                                                            PipeDirection.InOut,
                                                                            NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
                                                                            PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                                                            PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");

                await server.WaitForConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (server.IsConnected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");

                    if (server.CanRead) {
                        // Read something...
                    }

                    if (server.CanWrite) {
                        // Write something... 

                        await server.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                        server.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    }

                    server.Disconnect();

                    await HandleRequestAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task SendRequestAsync(int index, int counter, int max)
        {
            using (NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Index: {index} Counter: {counter}");

                    if (client.CanWrite) {
                        // Write something...

                        await client.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                        client.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    }

                    if (client.CanRead) {
                        // Read something...
                    }
                }

                if (counter <= max) {
                    await SendRequestAsync(index, ++counter, max).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{index} Done!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Assumptions:**

The way I expect it to work is for all the requests I make when I call `SendRequestAsync` to execute concurrently where each request then makes additional requests until it reaches `6` and finally, it should print "Done!".

**Remarks:**

1. I've tested it on .NET Framework 4.7.1 and .NET Core 2.0 and I get the same results.
2. The **communication** between clients and the server **is always local** to the machine where clients are web applications that can queue some jobs like launching 3rd-party processes and the server is going to be deployed as a Windows service on the same machine as the web server that these clients are deployed on.

Comment: Instead of using pipes you may want to use TCP.  See msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @jdweng The client and server are processes found on the same machine so TCP would be an overkill for this.

Comment: Absolutely wrong.  Millions of applications use TCP on a local PC.  Pipes are used for standard input and standard output but are rarely used to tunnel into an application.  Using TCP you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to debug application.

Comment: @jdweng TCP is used on local PCs that generally needs to make a remote connection, pipes are used heavily in IPC and I'm using it exactly for that, besides the client and the server there's also 3rd party processes that the server launches where these process have their stdin/out redirected but this isn't related the issue at hand so I didn't bother to go into details about it.

Comment: @jdweng debuggers may use TCP generally because they might need to make a remote connection either locally or externally to a remote machine but the latter isn't something I need.

Comment: Updated the remarks sections in my post to give some more context.

Comment: You have to wait for end of messages in pipes before processing.  So you need to use one of following 1) Ascii : Wait for a terminating character like a return to end each message 2) Ascii or Binary : Add a byte count to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Use Fix length messages.

Comment: @jdweng So, if I read you correctly, you're saying it hangs because I need to send something?

Comment: The recursive call to SendRequestAsync() is very ugly.  That constantly creates new client pipes, none get closed.  The show is probably over when it has created too many connections.  Throw this away and use the [MSDN sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) as a guide to get this right.

Comment: No.  You are getting only part of the message.  The stream in windows is updated using timers so a message can be split.  So when you read you are not getting the entire message in one chunk.

Comment: @HansPassant With all due respect, the MSDN example is synchronous, it doesn't really help me much and the "recursive" call doesn't enter an infinite loop, the connections do gets closed.

Comment: @jdweng But I don't send anything and if I was to send anything I call `WaitForPipeDrain` for this reason so the server and clients would wait for reads.

Comment: WaitForPipeDrain only reads available characters and doesn't know when the end of message is reached.  So it is possible to only get a piece of the received message and not the full message.

Comment: @jdweng I don't get it, in the example I posted I test the connection, I don't really care about sending and receiving messages, can you post a solution that works the way I specified? because I feel like the conversation is going to be too long for comments.and against SO policy.

Comment: If you are just getting logging info then it doesn't matter if you wait for end of message.  But if you are doing any processing of received data you usually have to wait for a complete message (even if you aren't sending anything).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the complete code after some iterations:

**PipeServer.cs**:

```
namespace AsyncPipes;

using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO.Pipes;

public static class PipeServer
{
    public static void WaitForConnection()
        => WaitForConnectionInitializer();

    private static void WaitForConnectionInitializer()
    {
        var context = new ServerContext();
        var server = context.Server;
    
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Waiting a client...");

            server.BeginWaitForConnection(WaitForConnectionCallback, context);
        }
        catch
        {
            // We need to cleanup here only when something goes wrong.
            context.Dispose();

            throw;
        }

        static void WaitForConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var (context, server, _) = ServerContext.FromResult(result);

            server.EndWaitForConnection(result);

            WaitForConnectionInitializer();

            BeginRead(context);
        }

        static void BeginRead(ServerContext context)
        {
            var (_, server, requestBuffer) = context;
            
            server.BeginRead(requestBuffer, 0, requestBuffer.Length, ReadCallback, context);
        }

        static void BeginWrite(ServerContext context)
        {
            var (_, server, responseBuffer) = context;
            
            server.BeginWrite(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length, WriteCallback, context);
        }

        static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var (context, server, requestBuffer) = ServerContext.FromResult(result);

            var bytesRead = server.EndRead(result);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                if (!server.IsMessageComplete)
                {
                    BeginRead(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    var index = BitConverter.ToInt32(requestBuffer, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{index} Request.");

                    BeginWrite(context);
                }
            }
        }

        static void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var (context, server, responseBuffer) = ServerContext.FromResult(result);
            var index = -1;
            
            try
            {
                server.EndWrite(result);
                server.WaitForPipeDrain();
                
                index = BitConverter.ToInt32(responseBuffer, 0);
                Console.WriteLine($"{index} Pong.");
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine($"{index} Disposed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class ServerContext : IDisposable
    {
        [NotNull]
        public byte[]? Buffer { get; private set; } = new byte[4];

        [NotNull]
        public NamedPipeServerStream? Server { get; private set; } = new ("PipesDemo",
                                                                        PipeDirection.InOut,
                                                                        NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
                                                                        PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                                                        PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        public void Deconstruct(out ServerContext context, out NamedPipeServerStream server, out byte[] buffer)
            => (context, server, buffer) = (this, Server, Buffer);

        public static ServerContext FromResult(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(result.AsyncState);
            
            return (ServerContext)result.AsyncState;
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Server is not null)
            {
                if (Server.IsConnected)
                {
                    Server.Disconnect();
                }
                
                Server.Dispose();
            }
            
            Server = null;
            Buffer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**PipeClient**:

```
public static class PipeClient
{
    public static void CreateConnection(int index)
    {
        using var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "PipesDemo", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
        client.Connect();

        var requestBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(index);
        client.Write(requestBuffer, 0, requestBuffer.Length);
        client.Flush();
        client.WaitForPipeDrain();
        Console.WriteLine($"{index} Ping.");

        var responseBuffer = new byte[4];
        var bytesRead = client.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            bytesRead = client.Read(responseBuffer, bytesRead - 1, responseBuffer.Length - bytesRead);
        }

        index = BitConverter.ToInt32(responseBuffer, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"{index} Response.");
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**:

```
namespace AsyncPipes;

internal class Program
{
    private const int MaxRequests = 1000;

    private static void Main()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>
        {
            Task.Run(PipeServer.WaitForConnection)
        };

        tasks.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, MaxRequests - 1)
                                .Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PipeClient.CreateConnection(i),
                                                                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can sort the messages and observe the following:

1. Connections are opened and closed correctly.
2. Data is sent and received correctly.
3. Finally, the server still waits for further connections.

**Updates:**

<s>Changed `PipeOptions.Asynchronous` to `PipeOptions.None` otherwise it seems like it hangs for the duration of the requests and only then processing them at once.</s>

PipeOptions.Asynchronous is simply causing a different order of execution than PipeOptions.None, and that's exposing a race condition / deadlock in your code. You can see the effect of it if you use Task Manager, for example, to monitor the thread count of your process... you should see it creeping up at a rate of appx 1 thread per second, until it gets to around 100 threads (maybe 110 or so), at which point your code runs to completion. Or if you add ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200) at the beginning. Your code has a problem where if the wrong ordering occurs (and that's made more likely by using Asynchronous), you create a cycle where it can't be satisfied until there are enough threads to run all of the concurrent ConnectAsyncs your main method has queued, which aren't truly async and instead just create a work item to invoke the synchronous Connect method (this is unfortunate, and it's issues like this that are one of the reasons I urge folks not to expose async APIs that simply queue works items to call sync methods). [Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26148).

Revised and simplified the example:

1. There's no true asynchronous `Connect` method for pipes, `ConnectAsync` uses `Task.Factory.StartNew` behind the scene so you might just as well use `Connect` and then pass the method (`SendRequest` in our example) that calls the synchronous `Connect` version to `Task.Factory.StartNew`.
2. The server is completely asynchronous now and as far as I can tell it works with no issues.
3. Fixed all of the BeginXXX/EndXXX methods.
4. Removed unnecessary try/catch blocks.
5. Removed unnecessary messages.
6. Refactor the code a bit to make it more readable and concise.
7. Removed the async/await version of the server as I refactored the code and didn't have time to update the async/await version but with the above version you can have an idea of how to do it and the new APIs are much more friendly and easy to deal with.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You are not awaiting for `BeginRead` / `BeginWrite` to end.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic I'm not sure to what you're referring to exactly but `BeginXXX` goes in pairs and I do call `EndXXX` for all of the methods inside the callbacks that are passed that's how this asynchronous pattern works and the example seems to work, a similar code that handles process scheduling still runs with no issues so please can you be more specific and tell me what exactly do you mean? :)

Comment: Reading from `request` buffer before `EndRead` is wrong. Also this code re-creates pipe handle for each request-response. Also using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is wrong because `BeginWaitForConnection` won't block and exit immediately. Also [server.Flush()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.cs,740) is blocking, but no-op for `PipeStream` and `WaitForPipeDrain` is blocking and can cause lock if one client is not reading from pipe.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Can you please provide an implementation that works based on your observations? or at least examples that demonstrate the problems? because with all due respect the things you say don't make much sense to me.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic "Reading from request buffer before EndRead is wrong" it was wrong if I had more than 4 bytes in the stream and I had to asynchronously get more data, so in the callback I'd have something like this
`int bytesRead = server.EndRead(result); var buffer = new byte[bytesRead]; // do something with the buffer.` but it's not the case I have a total of 4 bytes which makes an int and that's all the data.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic "Also this code re-creates pipe handle for each request-response" I'm creating many clients and there is only one server to handle the requests so can you be more specific?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic "Also using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning is wrong because BeginWaitForConnection won't block and exit immediately" this sentence doesn't make sense to me, can you elaborate? to me it reads like this "`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is wrong because I think that something that has nothing to do with it doesn't work." it's intentionally `LongRunning` but I'm not sure why do you think `BeginWaitForConnection` doesn't do its job here? if you ran the example you could see that it does.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic "WaitForPipeDrain is blocking and can cause lock if one client is not reading from pipe" can you please demonstrate this with an example?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Okay I've consulted a friend of mine and yes it seems like you're right when it comes to `EndRead` regardless to the fact that all the data I have makes the size of an int so I'll modify the example, it would be wonderful if you could share a complete modified example documented with all your points or something for all of us out there that misunderstand how to properly implement it for the sake of learning and general knowledge because I thought I got it right and here we are. :)

Comment: > `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`: `BeginWaitForConnection` doing it's work, but it's not "LongRunning". It's just schedules it's work to thread pool and exits, so `LongRunning` is wasting resources by creating and disposing new system thread. UPD: Sorry, it schedules PipeClients that are blocking and actually long running, and need non thread pool thread. I thought it schedules server tasks with LongRunning.

Comment: > re-creates pipe handle: `WaitForConnectionCallback` is calling `HandleRequest(++counter)` which creates `new NamedPipeServerStream`. To re-use handle you should do loop WaitForConnection -> Read\Write -> Disconnect -> WaitForConnection  -> ...

Comment: > WaitForPipeDrain is blocking example: just create one client in Main that connects, but doesn't read from pipe.

Comment: Sorry, no complete modified examples for today.

Comment: Also first write from client transfers clients impersonation token to server, so server can act on behalf of client. Client should validate server before writing to pipe.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Okay, thank you I'll modify the example when I'll have time, hopefully soon.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic As far as I know the implementation of pipes wasn't designed to be reused so you can''t really create a single pipe server for all of the incoming requests, it's one pipe stream per connection, I've tried, asked and double checked the answers on SO too but if you know how to make it work with the current implementation of pipes and can share an example of this I'd be more than pleased to remove my answer and select yours, regardless, as I pointed out you were right about the BeginXXX/EndXXX operations and I've fixed them.

Comment: It's "not designed" the same way as just regular listen socket. The only difference is that socket have backlog, but pipe server immediately responding with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. Client can use `WaitNamedPipeW` to opt-in to socket-like wait with timeout. More significant argument is that if you recreate handle for each client there is race between server and client. If server was not fast enough to open new handle, client will see pipe not found error. It usually means that server process is down, not just a temporary problem.

Comment: Pipe usually represent access to some resource and resource usually requires exclusive access (locking). Pipe server is usually lives on the same machine as client, so communication is mostly synchronous. Responding with pipe_busy makes this easier, so client doesn't block and can do something else while server is busy and server doesn't need to handle locking explicitly (all clients connections are serialized). If server wants to increase throughput it can create multiple threads and up to `nMaxInstances` pipe server handles. System will distribute clients between them

Comment: TPL version (acync\await) is recommended way to use this API. APM
is mostly obsolete and doesn't support cancellation, but I'm still targeting .net 4.0 :(

Comment: Task.WhenAll returns Task, you probably meant Task.WaitAll

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Yes it's true I use them for IPC so same machine. I used the async pattern because I a client of mine still uses .NET Framework 4.0 too but now we're in the process to move to .NET 6. Okay, I'll change `WhenAll` to `WaitAll` even through it's just an example and in the implementation I don't use either of them. Thank you for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 4):

When disconnecting, `WaitForPipeDrain()` can throw an `IOException` due to a broken pipe.

If this happens in your server `Task`, then it will never listen for the next connection, and all of the remaining client connections hang on `ConnectAsync()`.

If this happens in one of the client Tasks, then it will not continue to recurse and increment the counter for that index.

If you wrap the call to `WaitForPipeDrain()` in a `try`/`catch`, the program will continue running forever, because your function `HandleRequestAsync()` is infinitely recursive.

In short, to get this to work:

1. Handle `IOException` from `WaitForPipeDrain()`
2. `HandleRequestAsync()` has to finish at some point.

Comment: I tried to wrap `WaitForPipeDrain` with a try/catch block but I still get the same results and `HandleRequestAsync` should run forever so it shouldn't end in order to listen for further requests and if it entered an infinite loop I should have seen the GC doing much work due to allocations made by `WaitForConnectionAsync` or get `StackOverflowException` and none of them happens so I dunno. :)

Comment: Okay, I do get an exception, I've wrapped the calls with a try/catch and now I can see it.